# How can I convert a sound file to .mif using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio-processing

I want to have a mif file from the sound signal of a for example mp3 file. How can I do it using MATLAB?

Thanks,
BooMZ!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) First I googled "mp3 matlab" and the top hit was this [this function that reads in MP3 files](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6152-MP3WRITE%20and%20MP3READ), then I googled "matlab mif audio" and the top hit was [this function that writes out mif files](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19-delta-sigma-toolbox/content/delsig/printmif.m) . Have you tried either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As result, I couldn't find any solution to convert a MP3 file to mif. But I could convert wav file to mif. It's the instructions:
First you must drag and drop your wav file to MatLab. MatLab will make a array from wav file. Finally, you must write the data array to a file with mif format. (you can do it by `fprintf`)